# What could make a planet more radioactive at night?

Tags: astronomy, radioactivity

In the story of my video game, I want a group of colonists to land at dawn on an alien planet and have to terraform or build protective structures before sundown (several earth days).

I want the death of the colony if they fail the lethal dose to be within less than an hour, so I would prefer to have a bad-science-instant radiation death instead of death from cold or creatures coming out at night.

I want the game to take place during the day.

The planet is a rocky planet with water.

**Edit**: There could be on a moon if required.

Comment: What if the planet doesn't become radioactive, but instead has a moon that is so radioactive that it will kill the colony as soon as it reaches a certain position in the (night) sky?

Comment: Instadeath from radiation requires a stunningly high rad count, on the order of a gamma ray burst.  Can they die within hours?

Comment: RonJohn within hours is fine, I guess lethal dose within minuets would serve the same emotional purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I was under the impression that a slow painful death wouldn't fit the plot, hence no slow freezing to death or being devoured one by one by animals. Dying from radiation poisoning over the course of hours is much more agonizing than freezing to death. In addition to vomiting, hair loss, bleeding from every orifice, and tooth loss, you would have to watch your fellow colonists also suffer through this at the same time. I would pick the freezing night planet any day of their solar week.

Comment: @Anthony The only thing on your list that will happen with a reasonably fast radiation death is the vomiting.  The rest of your symptoms are only for slow deaths.

Comment: Note that death by radiation in hours means central nervous system effects--you keel over in minutes.  It also means roughly 30Sv of exposure.  (The data at this level is obviously quite poor.  This sort of exposure to a human only occurs with a criticality accident and there haven't been many of those in the world.)

Comment: I like the premise but why would humans ever consider suitable a planet that could kill them every day? And not only them, but also every crop, plant or livestock that could come with them?
It reminds me of another game: [Full Metal Planet](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20/full-metal-planete), whose premise has similities. The planet has regular but deadly tides and the players must gather ore within two giant tides. In your scenario, the waters could be radioactive enough to kill your colonists when the tide rise, but become benign when the waters retire.

Comment: Does it have to be radiation? Radiation is a slow killer in most cases. Toxins on the other hand, can kill quite quickly. A plant which releases a nerve agent at night, and the chemical breaks down rapidly when it rises above a certain temperature. It could be as simple as having to huddle very close to a campfire to stay alive the first night. Maybe it's only lethal when it builds up in the bloodstream, so brief (<5 minute) forays at night would be fine, but permanent damage starts setting in within 20 minutes. Your body could get rid of the toxin during a couple hours away from exposure.

Comment: Does it have to be a natural setup? Why not have an artificial satellite orbiting the planet trying to sterilize the surface with a gamma ray weapon? Or maybe it's just an ancient malfunctioning terraformer. Could add some cosmic mystery to your setting.

Comment: @Harabeck Ancient malfunctioning terraformer following the night shadow, bringing death at every passing.

Comment: I realise that you don't want death by animals but, what about hordes of trillions of underground-dwelling scarab beetles? They hide away from sunlight every daytime but come out after dark, usually to eat the abundant fast-growing fungus that springs up late in the day once the dusk fully approaches but much-preferring to taste meat? Death in minutes without shelter. No hunting, you are just overcome. Impossible to poison, every time you dig for them in the crevices they just scuttle away deeper.

Comment: @LorenPechtel You need significantly more than 30Sv/Gy to kill someone in minutes. Assuming you're looking at the same table I am, you've mistook the onset of nausea symptoms line for the time to death line (1-2 days). From what I've read about the intended use of neutron bombs they targeted an 80-100Gy (or 400-500Sv because most of the dose would be in the form of neutrons) for immediate incapacitation (although it'd still take the rest of the body some time to figure out it was dead).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome  http://www.fact-index.com/n/ne/neutron_bomb_1.html

Comment: @DanNeely I was only figuring incapacitation--after that it doesn't really matter how fast you die.

Comment: @Anthony If that were the case then they could evade the moon by moving around the planet.

Comment: @Pharap Only if they are able to sustain that pace indefinitely. Which may also defeat the purpose of colonising the planet.

Comment: I don't suppose an option would be that the infrastructure has to be built by daybreak rather than sundown. This would add the difficulty of constructing at "night" by moonlight or artificial lighting. At daybreak the radiation from the star itself could be lethal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A highly radioactive gas that becomes much lighter when heated by the sun and rises to the top layers of the atmosphere or disperses into harmless levels.

I'm not sure if such a gas could exist and do that in such a dramatic and straightforward manner in an earth-like atmosphere, but i guess if it works for you it would be plausible in a planet with much lower atmospheric pressure (that could also change at times by moon gravitational fields or something), where the gas weight would be more significant in it's behavior.

Also such an event would be preceded by ominous windstorms, perfect for dramatic effect.

OR.. 
The gas is on higher layers of the atmosphere during the day and liquefies at night due to the temperature drop, causing a radioactive rainstorm with the radioactive liquid rapidly returning to gaseous form at sunup.

Comment: Instead of a chemical that gets lighter a  radioactive plant spore maybe? The rainstorm idea is great.

Comment: I don't really see how the spores add up in such a scenario... Maybe the plants emit the gas, like suggested in another answer, during decomposition, or just maybe..... as their perfume... (ominous smile)

Comment: I thought spores like hot air balloons that heat up and rise during the day. But I much preferred the rainstorm idea anyway. If I put you in the credits would you want to go by Frixus?

Comment: I suggest adding some details about Pluto's Gate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploutonion_at_Hierapolis This cave emits toxic gases which settle in valleys like pools of death when the winds drop. The planet could be modified such that these toxic gases are emitted in much larger amounts over wider areas. Then also have the winds die down at night. Thus, dilution of the noxious miasma is minimized resulting in instant death.

Comment: Another comment. A gas which is buoyant enough to float above oxygen and then reverse that buoyancy is incredibly unlikely. Radioactive gases either tend to be very heavy and sink or require being made radioactive via neutron radiation. Not impossible, but it's more likely the people are directly radiated rather than from some gas that only comes at night.

Comment: Sandy Chapman, I thought about that, of course all that is highly unlikely, or at least exotic, but "sciency" enough for a video game in my opinion. A plausible scenario for a gas with such a behavior (as long as it's constantly produced) is the gas being a complex compound, so it can have pretty much any properties one wants. It would break up, of course, over the course of radioactive decay, but it's exactly that decay that causes the radiation. PStag I would be honored, Frixus is fine. Just be sure to tell us the game's name and release date when you have them..

Answer (score 46):

The ground worldwide might be rich in radioactive ores, but you have to dig at least half a mile down to find them.

However, many plants have roots that do go that far down. Those plants are radioactive. Staying away from them is enough to be safe by day.

But, by night, their flowers bloom, releasing [radon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon), a radioactive noble gas.

The plants don't extract radon from the ground. It is a byproduct of the decay of thorium and uranium. Radon is a gas, and has a half-life of 3.8 days. The radioactivity will peak at night during blooms, but radiation levels might already be safe enough by day after the radioactive gas has spread thin.

In temperate areas, spring will be the most dangerous season of the year. In tropical areas, though, blooms might happen every single night, regardless of season.

Comment: Mmmm delicious radon honey.

Comment: Why is the pollen contain radon? Pollen's a solid; radon's a gas. Unless the pollen is using the radon, it would make more sense to release radon through stomata.

Comment: @tox123 you're right. I'll edit, thanks!

Comment: Won't work. "*Radon is a gas, and has a half-life of 3.8 days.*" If you start with enough radon to *kill you instantly*, a tremendous amount of radon, now you have half as much which is still plenty to kill you. Radon gas is very heavy, which is why it accumulates in basements, and is unlikely to disperse easily.

Comment: @schwern 3.8 earth days. On this planet days are "several earth days" if the radon was released at sunset it would have enough time to fall to a quarter naturally. And the plants would be absorbing the radioactive pollen through the night.

Comment: @PStag: Remember that radon is a noble gas, and thus chemically quite inert. (That's why it's a gas in the first place, while most other elements of comparable atomic mass tend to form solid compounds.) That means that plants can't easily transport it even if they wanted to, and also that once it's in the air, it cannot be easily reabsorbed. You might want to go with a more chemically reactive element than radon. (Also, note that being inside a plant won't stop a radioisotope from decaying. If anything, being concentrated together can accelerate decay. Those would be some pretty hot plants.)

Comment: Why are you fighting what radon want's to do? If you need it to disperse after the plants dump it at night then put the plants on a hill and stay out of death valley. Don't like death valley? Dump it on a river and send it out to sea.

Comment: @CandiedOrange OP asked about the need for colonitsts to build fast in order to avoid death at night. It might be that they are on a plain, and the channeling of the gas is the engineering they have to do in order to survive long-term.

Comment: @Renan sounds reasonable. Just need a way to explain the threat so they start work before they die. Maybe an advance team was killed by this the night before.

Answer (score 23):

What if the planet doesn't become radioactive, but instead has a moon that is so radioactive that it will kill the colony as soon as it reaches a certain position in the (night) sky?

Assume it is radioactive enough to have such an effect but weak enough that it has to be just high enough in the sky for it to be lethal. This adds an extra sense of urgency towards the end of the day, as they would be able to see the moon already having said impact a certain distance away and getting closer by the minute.

The camp could be in a box canyon with a high mountain creating a natural shield from the radiation which protects them from getting radiation poison before the moon is close enough to kill them instantly.

Comment: This could work, I can't have them in a canyon as they need to move around, but a radioactive moon is a nice theme.

Comment: So what happens when the moon is high in the day sky ? Or does it follow an unusual orbit, that keeps the moon on the night side ?

Comment: Kubo and the two Strings?

Comment: @Ghajini I thought the same. But the planet could be tidal locked to the moon, or since the story is only the length of one planet's days the moon is only in the night sky during the story.

Comment: By “high in the sky” do you mean with thinner atmosphere absorbing or reflecting the dangerous radiation and high-energy particles, or do you mean the radiation from the moon is coherent like a laser?  Maybe it is a derelict weapons platform.

Comment: @can-ned_food Actually, that sounds like a new answer there.  Either way, it seems like you would need to explain why they can't simply build a settlement away from the orbital plane of the moon.

Comment: @PStag: If the planet is tidally locked to the moon, that just means that, viewed from the planet's surface, the moon will always stay in (approximately) the same place in the sky. Which makes it useless for your purpose, since it will never rise or set (except in places where the moon is very close to the horizon, where it might bob up and down a bit if its orbit isn't perfectly circular).

Comment: What if…the planet turned out to be…Earth!

Comment: @ilmariKaronen true, I guess I mean the moon tidally locked between the sun and the planet. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: @PStag: It isn't, at least not for long; the collinear [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) are all unstable. (Also, that's not what [tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) normally means.)

Comment: Can't work! We have a name for celestial bodies that give off that much radiation, so much radiation that it could slowly cook you. We call them STARS. Anything that radioactive would be glowing blue hot.

Comment: It is impossible to have a moon that is only above the horizon during the night.  There is another thread where I come up with an explanation of how a moon can be above the horizon in both day and night but is never bright enough to be visible except at night.  But that is no help here because the moon will be equally radioactive night and day.  But like Earth's moon the radioactive moon might be on the night side of the planet for days at a time - longer if you adjust the planet's rotation and the moon's orbital period properly.

Comment: Well my original suggestion was based on the premise of "maybe it isn't the planet at night but something external to the planet at night." As in to consider something external but still temporal. Maybe it's a satellite. Maybe it's a death ray that is on the moon and is somehow triggered when it is in a night sky. I appreciate the due diligence to science, but conceptually, moon is a stand in for "something that would only be in the night sky".

Comment: Aside from the other comments, I don't understand how the height in the sky would be able to change anything.

Comment: My original idea also mentions a possible natural shield that protects them until the source is beyond it.

Comment: @Aron A small black hole would release a large amount of radiation and would not "glow blue hot". A small enough stable black hole won't suck things into it unless they actually fall into it, so it could maintain a stable orbit.

Comment: @forest umm no. Firstly. Where did the blackhole come from, it's not a stable arrangement. Something either must have been feeding it, or you are well within the progenitor star radius. Second, the progenitor star going supernova should have destroyed the planet. Third the hard radiation from the blackhole would have vapourize the planet. Whatever happens there would be no life in the same system as a blackhole. Period. Heck even the neutrino radiation alone would sterilise the system.

Comment: @Aron How it got there shouldn't matter (it could have been drifting and caught in orbit), but would the radiation of a stable black hole really be intense enough to destroy the planet itself? And neutrino radiation is very, very weak. A star going supernova would create a lethal dose of even neutrinos, but a mere black hole? They're radioactive but not _that_ radioactive!

Comment: @forest "drifting and caught in orbit"... You have never played KSP have you? Any conceivable capture event would have "sterilise" the system.

Comment: @forest kinematically speaking a blackhole has a coefficient of restitution of 0...event horizon. Gravity is weak, so slingshot is out of the question. Leaving a capture event = the blackhole hitting something heavier than itself. This would release enough energy to destroy the system.

Answer (score 12):

This solution is a bit extreme, but if your planet's solar system is doing something very exotic, you could get just that:

### Have the entire solar system travel at relativistic speed through space

You can see some more specific details in this [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/4782/1957) for a question of mine (predating worldBuilding.SE so asked on Astronomy.SE) about an even more exotic setup.

Basically, if the entire system is traveling *very* fast (90% - 99% of the speed of light, or even faster) relative to the galaxy it's passing through, than two separate phenomena create a single bright<sup>1</sup>, high-radiation circular patch in the sky:

1. [Light aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_aberration) and [relativistic beaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_beaming) means all the starlight reaching the planet is concentrated in a disk 'straight ahead' in the direction of the system's movement (size of disk becomes smaller the faster the system travels). This light is also strongly [blue-shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) to a UV, X-ray and Gamma ray level (so radioactive and lethal)
2. At those speeds, any interstellar particles the star hits will behave as [cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Massive_cosmic_rays_compared_to_photons) (I encourage you to read the list of their [effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Effects) - they are excellent for the epic instant death you need).

So, you have a very exotic planet (which is a good reason to try and build a temporary base on it - for research etc...) - which have a deadly "bright patch" in its night sky. During the day, there will still be insane atmospheric interference, lightning storms, winds etc. But the planet itself shields the base from the worst of the effect. But, a bit before the bright patch rises over the horizon things get much worse, and become instantly lethal when the patch is in the visible night-sky.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Note that this "bright patch" will likely not be visible to human eyes - it can be detected by instruments (and by its deadly effect), but with high enough velocity, it won't provide visible light.

Comment: Might be hard to land on a planet in such a system, though, unless you're departing another body in that system (in which case you'll already be adapted to the effects of this, or you'd never get as far as to space travel to begin with)...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, sort of - entering and matching velocity with the system requires FTL or an insane acceleration, but these are common in many sci-fi settings. After you reach the system and match velocity, the main difficulty is that your ship is also bombarded by that radiation and cosmic rays - so it better by shielded by first-grade handwavioum, but, aren't they all? ;)

Comment: Isn't this opposite of what is asked? The question wants death during dark hours not while the bright patch is visible? You death with light was wanted a sun with high radiation would do.

Comment: @VilleNiemi - keep in mind that this "bright patch" is very focused and with high enough velocity can be blue-shifted above the visible spectrum, so instruments will detect it, but it doesn't brighten the sky or provide any visible illumination. - I'll correct the answer's text to make it clearer, "bright" is maybe a poor word choice for this...

Comment: The problem with this solution (and other similar ones, like a pulsar / black hole companion star emitting hard radiation) is that the radiation source will only be in the night sky for half the planet's year (and will only rise exactly at sundown on one single day of the year, if that). Which kind of makes one wonder why the colonists would decide to land on that exact day.

Comment: I think the atmosphere quickly ends up stripped.

Comment: @LorenPechtel plausibly, though I reckon high-relativistic particles are actually _less_ of a problem for the atmosphere than relatively calm solar wind is: cosmic rays just pass through the higher atmosphere without much effect, and in the lower atmosphere it doesn't much matter even if they hit lots of air molecules – the density is so high that the resulting ions won't get far.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen If you are planning to explore a planet, and can only do so for half of a "day" cycle, you would want as much of that time as possible to be daytime so you can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

Have a magnetic anomaly by which the planet's magnetic field almost completely disappears on the night side. During the day, the solar wind of high-energy protons is deflected by the planet and focused to the poles. At night, the particles hit the planet's atmosphere, producing a shower of gamma radiation from the resulting collisions. The solar wind is just as strong at night as it is during the day because it takes it a few days to reach the planet so it doesn't vanish when the sun sets.

Night sky might have an inherent glow to it from the amount of radiation. Also the planet's poles would have an incredibly bright aurora, and the arctic circles would be uninhabitable.

Answer (score 6):

A highly radioactive asteroid belt, outside the orbit of the planet.

On the day-side, the asteroid belt is both further away and (very) partially shielded by the sun.  On the night-side, the radiation is closer, and more direct/focused (at dawn/dusk the radiation is spread over a wider area due to the angle it arrives at, like the sun is in winter)

This would mean that the radiation would increase rapidly at a slowing rate until peaking at midnight, and then drop of slowly and an increasing rate - much like sunlight during the day.

But, really, radiation is a *slow* killer.  Yes, less than an hour of exposure can be deadly, but it will kill you over a matter of days/weeks, not within that hour.  With a poorly insulated planet set up right, you could go from ~20°C to ~-30°C in a couple of hours (The Sahara can drop from a 50°C day-time temperature to below freezing at night), and without proper protective measures the cold-shock will kill you within 10 minutes.  Or the hypothermia will set in within 30 minutes, and kill you within 2 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get the effect is to have it coincidental to the daylight. There is simply a powerful source of hard radiation nearby at roughly the plane of the planet's rotation so that the surface is bombarded with radiation for half the day. The colonist then can choose which part of the day they can work to build their colony by timing their landing and oddly enough chose having natural light over nighttime.

That said, if they have spaceships and planet rotates fairly slowly they should be able to simply hop around the planet to avoid being exposed to the radiation. The ships would simply ferry people near areas soon to be exposed to radiation to an area that was recently protected from radiation.

Well, I am sure you have some workaround that sticks them to a single location and it is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same as the [Moon answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/112083/27708)?

Comment: @can-ned_food: Well, a radioactive moon (especially one so extremely radioactive as to produce instantly lethal radiation levels on the planet's surface) is rather physically implausible to begin with. A pulsar or a black hole with a jet pointed right at the solar system seems a lot more plausible, even if the precise alignment may require a bit of a lucky coincidence.

Comment: If the planet has a rotational axis tilted more like Uranus (97°) or Pluto (122.5°) instead of like Earth (23.5°) or Jupiter (3°) then A) the sun rises/sets throughout the year instead of the "day" and B) your pulsar-source could be above/below the solar plane, pointing into it, so that it affects the planet for half the "day"

Comment: @can-ned_food Yes? I am trying to answer the same question, so my answer will be similar to other answers. Main reason I made a separate answer is probably (I have actually forgotten) because the moon itself is an unnecessarily complex assumption especially as regards to the link to the time of day. Any radiation source in direction opposite to the sun does better IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

You could have high daytime temperatures coupled with porous soil that continuously leaks radioactive gas. As it gets colder at night, the gas accumulates at ground level.

Answer (score 2):

Night is only correlated with the death radiation.

If your place is a moon tidally locked to a gas giant, night on the planet-facing side is closer to the star than the during the day. It may be the planet's magnetosphere is shaped so that it offers significantly less protection there.

If the solar system is being bathed in death radiation from an external source during part of the year night would be pointed straight at it. This means death happens for half a sidereal day rather than solar day and the effect would be exactly opposite half a (your planet) year later, but with a far enough orbit a half year might be long enough not to matter (100 Earth years on Pluto).

Answer (score 1):

Or swap day for night... The planet orbits a binary star system, where one star is as bright as normal day, and the other star is so bright it insta-kills.

Maybe make the other star a neutron star or something, so it doesn't show in visible wavelengths.

Comment: Wouldn't the planet have to sit between the two stars for this to happen? Such a system would be too unstable to exist for long enough for a planet to form.

Answer (score 0):

In line with Rennan's plant suggestion, I was thinking of highly radioactive [Horta-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_in_the_Dark) animals that come out at night in droves. For some reason they sleep in lead houses during the day :-)

Answer (score 0):

The whole planetary system lays in a proximity of a place where intensive astronomical explosion occurred recently (less than a million years ago) like supernova or neutron star/blackhole collision. It would result in very high radiation from a matter that was ejected by the event.

The only problem that I see, is that the phenomenon would be seasonal: during some seasons the radiation would appear at nights and during some seasons it will be daily. You can at least put some protoplanetary matter in an inner orbit to prevent daytime-radiation from occurring during some seasons...

[image: a simple sketch of the setting]

Answer (score 0):

I like the "radioactive moon" idea, but you could do it the other way around: the planet is a moon of a highly radioactive gas giant. As long as the colony is facing away from the gas giant, it's protected from the radiation, but it will rotate towards it too.

Note that: 1) The times that the gas giant "rises" or "sets" is separate from  day and night (when the *sun* rises and sets).  2) Most moons of gas giants have one face always facing the planet, so it doesn't rise or set, but you're permitting bad science.